# How to Create text string in MySQL against all records in a view

Tags: mysql, string, sql-timestamp

I'm looking to see if I can create a view where I can create a third column that always shows a text string made up of the Current Year-Current WeekNo so a sample would be 2021-26 or 2021-23.

The whole point is that I effectively need to timestamp set columns against the year-week so the view would be

Column1 - Type
Column2 - Value
Column3 - year-week

An event then copies this info to another table where the I have an accurate time stamp in the format year-week.

MySqls own timestamp is not relevant for this task and I can get the single result using `(select WEEK(CURDATE(),0)) as 'Week_No', (SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())) as 'Year'`

Any input would be good.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding something like this to the field list:

```
concat(year(curdate()), '-', week(curdate(), 1)) as 'year_week'
```

- [`week`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) has various options for how to show/calculate the week number.
- [`dual`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced

[image]

e.g.:

```
select
    'value' as value,
    'type' as type,
    concat(year(curdate()), '-', week(curdate(), 1)) as 'year_week'
from dual
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/227666

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you I didn't even think to consider a concat